# JPA many to many relationship with specific cascade type

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

For my task i need to create many to many relationship using JPA, but junctional table is manually specified with extra columns.
Data structure looks like this:

- Books (id, name, published, genre, rating)
- Authors (id, name, gender, born)
- Book-Author (id, book-id,  author-id)

I created such entities:

Author:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", length = 60)
  private String name;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Gender gender;

  private Date born;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = 
     true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<AuthorBook> authorBooks = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Book:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private Date published;

  private String genre;

  private BigDecimal rating;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = 
    FetchType.EAGER)
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private Set<AuthorBook> authorBooks = new HashSet<>();

}
```

AuthorBook:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"book", "author"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "author_book")
public class AuthorBook implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  private Book book;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
  private Author author;
}
```

Dataset I inserts to my tables:

Books table:

```
 id       name              published       genre               rating
 1     'Залишенець'         '2005-02-03'    'historical novel'  '5'
 2     'Ключ'               '1999-01-01'    'novel'             '3'
 3     'Effective Java'     '2001-03-02'    'technical'         '5'
 4     'Java Concurrency'   '2006-04-23'    'technical'         '4'
 5     'Java Puzzlers'      '2005-02-02'    'technical'         '4'
 6     'Patterns'           '2002-06-25'    'technical'         '3'
 7     'Harry Potter'       '1997-06-26'    'fantasy'           '5'
 8     'The Programmer'     '1999-09-21'    'education'         '5'
 9     'The Lost Symbol'     null           'crime'             '4'
```

Author table:

```
id            name                  gender       born    
1      'Шкляр Василь Миколайович'   'male'      '1951-06-10'
2      'Joshua Bloch'               'male'      '1961-07-28'
3      'Martin Fowler'              'male'       null
4      'Chad Fowler'                'male'       null
5      'J. K. Rowling'              'female'    '1965-07-31'
6      'Dan Brown'                  'male'      '1964-06-22'
7      'Suzanne Collins'            'female'    '1962-08-10'
```

AuthorBook table:

```
id   book_id   author_id
 1    1       1
 2    2       1
 3    3       2
 4    4       2
 5    5       2
 6    6       3
 7    9       6
 8    8       4
 9    7       5
```

When I delete, for example, book with id=2, it deletes author with id=1. Is there any way to delete book while not deleting binded author. With author table the same thing: when deleting author i shouldn't delete his books. I'm new in Spring Data JPA, so sorry if this question is dumb.

**UPDATE**

I remove cascade type from @ManyToOne annotation in AuthorBook entity and now it looks like this:

```
public class AuthorBook implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  private Book book;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
  private Author author;
}
```

Book and Author entities stays the same.
Now when I try to remove book with id=1 using JPA's deleteById(idValue) it throws

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Book with id 1
```

It actually deletes book from books table, but doesn't delete associated records from AuthorBook table, I mean no book with id=1 stays in the books table, but in AuthorBook table still there is record:

```
id   book_id   author_id
1     1         1
```

MySql screenshots after deleting book record with id=1

AuthorBook table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls22r.png)

Book table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv4GP.png)

Author table:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWesR.png)

Comment: Sure. remove `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`from your ManyToOne: it doesn't make any sense. You can't delete the author of a book when deleting the book, because the author has written other books, and the deletion will thus fail anyway, since other books still reference the author. Why did you add this cascade attribute in the first place, since it does exactly what you don't want to do?

Comment: @JBNizet   Well, I know that cascade = CascadeType.ALL doesn't make sense, but if I remove it, it doesn't delete records.  I really don't know, is there any way to delete authors without  deleting associated books  and deleting books without deleting associated authors?

Comment: If it doesn't delete the book, then edit your question, post the code you tried to delete the book (without the cascade on the ManyToOne), tell us precisely what you expectit to do and what it does instead.

Comment: @JBNizet Edited my question with your advices, now I don't know how handle the situation with not deleting associated records in AuthorBook table, while deleting books and authors.

Comment: Your tables seem to be incorrectly defined. Why do you have quotes around your ids in the AuthorBook table, but not the in other tables? They should have the same type. And you should have foreign key constraints defined. If you get the exception you mention, it means that you have NOT deleted the book, since the book doesn't exist in the first place. So obviously, no cascade can happen: your data are in an inconsistent state because you didn't define foreign key constraints.

Comment: @JBNizet Quotes around ids were my bad, forgot to delete posting entities here, sorry. In db ids stored without quotes. Added screenshots how tables look in MySql after deleting book with id=1. As you can see record in table AuthorBook with reference to book with id=1 stays in db. If the reason is foreign key constraints, so how to define them correctly.

Comment: Read my previous comment. A foreign key constraint will **prevent you** from deleting a book if it's still referenced in AuthorBook. That's a good thing, because tehre shouldn't be any AUthorBook referencing an unexisting book. You haven't defined constraints, so you did that mistake before: you have an AuthorBook that references the book with ID 1, which doesn't exist. Now you're trying to delete, using JPA, the book with ID 1, and you complain that it doesn't delete the AuthorBook entries. Read your exception: it doesn't because the book with ID 1 doesn't even exist.

Comment: @JBNizet Is there any option to delete a book from books table and delete record associated with it from AuthorBook table while not deleting author associated with them? I mean deleting book with id=1, will delete record (id=1 book_id=1, author_id=1) from AuthorBook, but will bot delete author with id=1 from authors table?

Comment: Yes. There is. That's what your code should do. But you need to delete a book that actually exists. Not an unexisting book.

Answer (score 1):

You are enforcing the entities to delete the dependent records with this tag
 `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

The meaning of CascadeType.ALL is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.

If you don't want to delete the dependent records remove this tag from the entity which might cause to leave an orphan records in your table(not a good practice).

Comment: Is there any way to delete authors without deleting associated books and deleting books without deleting associated authors, just removing records in junctional table AuthorBook?